# what are the inner angles of a tetragonal trapezohedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, metric-geometry

I am making a 3D wooden lantern in the shape of a [Tetragonal Trapezohedron](https://www.polyhedra.net/en/model.php?name-en=square-trapezohedron). Think of a hollow Tetragonal Trapezohedron 3D object, where each face is a plank of wood. I am trying to determine the angles between the two planes, I should cut plank of wood at.

For example the kite has the following dimensions, Short edge: 236 mm, Long edge: 403 mm. Face angles: 55°, 102°, 101°, 102°. The thickness of each face is 25 mm.

I have tried cutting the long edges at 45° then taping them all together, but there is a gap, meaning that 45° is too large. The angle for the long edge should be less then 45°.

How do you determine the angle between the long edges and the short edges?

Comment: If you make faces with three equal angles (which is your case, in practice), then all dihedral angles are the same, see here for their measure: http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/TetragonalTrapezohedron.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This site](http://dmccooey.com/polyhedra/TetragonalTrapezohedron.html)
(to which @Aretino already pointed)
lists the dihedral angles as $105.14^\circ$,
as illustrated below.
(I verified that this angle is same at every edge.)
So you should bevel at half this angle, $52.6^\circ$.

---

[image: DihedralAng]

          

<sup>Side view illustrating the dihedral angle.</sup>

---

[image: Upright]

          

<sup>Front view of Tetragonal Trapezohedron.</sup>

---

Comment: @Travis: Oops. I'll replace with my own figure.

Comment: Joseph, what program did you use to generate these images?

Comment: @Travis: Mathematica, opacity 75% so the structure is more clear.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke I will check tonight and report back. Everything makes sense.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke it worked! I have a great looking lantern. Thank you

Comment: @Stevensmethurst: Perhaps post a photo?

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke here is half of it, the other half should be done this weekend https://www.instagram.com/p/B1qNzMHB3MX/

Comment: @Stevensmethurst: Beautiful!